# PrimeNG dropdown's options are outside component's DOM in jest unit test

Tags: angular, jestjs, primeng

I recently updated PrimeNG to version 15.3.0. Some of my Jest unit tests are failing because dropdown options are rendered outside of component's DOM. Before the update they were rendered in the app as a popup otuside component's DOM as well but somehow, in unit tests I had access to them and I could see them when I would console.log them DOM.
Is there a workaround so that I can test dropdown's options based on the DOM and not component's instance?